# Charting in real time

Tags: javascript, charts, real-time

What is the best solution for charts that refresh 5+ times a second? I'll even drop that to once every 1-5 seconds if I can get charts that don't "blink" when redrawing.

I'm willing to use any technology, but considering the application already uses WebSockets you can recommend just about anything and it can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)?

The "poll for data" example on this page may be what you're looking for: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

Comment: I tried Flot previously, didn't like it at all. I will give it another try though.

Answer (score 1):

[image: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/assets/yuilib.jpg]

The [YUI Charts Control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/charts/charts-xhr-polling.html) provides built-in support for iterative polling for data over XHR using an XHR DataSource instance

Comment: That would work great, but incoming data is evented not polled for.